# Finding out whether normal points outwards or inwards

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Consider $F(x,y,z)=(x,x^2y,0)$ and $$\Omega=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid(x^2+y^2)^2<z<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$$

I want to compute $\iint_{\partial\Omega}(F\cdot\nu)\text{ds}$ where $\nu$ is the normal pointing outwards.

I have that $\partial\Omega = \Sigma^1\cup\Sigma^2$ where

$$\Sigma^1=\{\sigma^1(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r^4)\mid (r,\theta)\in(0,1)\times(0,2\pi)\}$$

$$\Sigma^2=\{\sigma^2(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r)\mid (r,\theta)\in(0,1)\times(0,2\pi)\}$$

So when I compute the normals I get:

$$\sigma^1_r\times\sigma^1_\theta=(-4r^4\cos\theta,-4r^4\sin\theta,r)$$
$$\sigma^2_r\times\sigma^2_\theta=(-r\cos\theta, -r\sin\theta,r)\, $$

I know that the first one points inwards and the second one outwards (it's written in the textbook's solution) but I don't know how they find that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing the space $\Omega$ in the $(r,z)$ plane for $\theta=0$ can help visualize thing, see this [wolfram alpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20r%3Ez%3Er%5E4%20for%20r%3E0). When $\theta=0$, your normal vectors become:
$$
\sigma^1_r\times\sigma^1_\theta=(-4r^4,0,r) \\
\sigma^2_r\times\sigma^2_\theta=(-r,0,r)
$$
and both point upwards towards the left. Consequently, the lower one (on $\Sigma_1$) is pointing inwards whereas the upper one (on $\Sigma_2$) is pointing outwards.